# Laravel orderBy does not exist

Tags: laravel

I'm doing the simple query

```
  $offers = Offer::join('offer_speciality', 'offers.id', 'offer_speciality.offer_id')
            ->join('specialities', 'offer_speciality.speciality_id', 'specialities.id')
            ->when($speciality, function($query, $speciality) {
                 return $query->where('specialities.number', $speciality)->get();
            })
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9);
```

and then error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not
>   exist

I'm not sure what is it?

Answer (score 2):

At the point of running `->get()` a collection is being returned and `->orderBy()`  is not a function you can run on a collection with all the functions available being listed in the documention.

You've got your `->get()` before your `->orderBy()` and that wont work. Plus you don't need `->get()` as you've got `->paginate(9)`

You need:

```
$offers = Offer::join('offer_speciality', 'offers.id', 'offer_speciality.offer_id')
      ->join('specialities', 'offer_speciality.speciality_id', '=', 'specialities.id')
      ->when($speciality, function($query, $speciality) {
           return $query->where('specialities.number', $speciality)
      })
      ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(9)
```

Comment: His join is also missing a '='

Comment: sure, that's my error (again - I thought there is a bug in Laravel lol), without '=' is still working

Comment: I thought it did but wasnt 100%

Comment: guys, can you tell my why after this query I cannot access other models from $offers? I'm trying $offers->people and it's not working

Comment: `$Offers` is a collection of results. If you want to access a relationship you need to loop through each `$offer` and run the relationship from that. ie `foreach`